# Data Structure of the Periodic Table of Elements

Tags: java, enums, cheminformatics

My goal is to use the periodic table of elements (or a list) to get information about a specific element in Java. I want to search it by atomic number and symbol (but that conversion should be simple).

I found that information in [this JQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-pte/downloads/detail?name=jquery.pte.json&can=2). But it is stored as a JSON file.

It seems like it would be most efficient to hardcode the information (since it doesn't change too often and due to performance reasons), but how do I convert JSON to a hardcoded `enum`?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library and does not run in Java. Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: There exist several libraries to parse `JSON` files into `Hashmap` and `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes, of course! I didn't write anything else, right?

Comment: I personally like GSON which allows you to map JSON objects to java objects that you define, you may want to look into it, https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: We're talking about around 120 elements, each holding 3 basic informations. Do you really think that the file size matters? It will be around 4KB large. Start doing something, and it will be fast enough, whatever the solution you choose. A computer performs several millions of operations per second. Your table will contain 120 elements.

Comment: Its not that Periodic Table changes on a weekly basis. Why not hardcode the table in your code and add accessor methods to get the elements as you want?

Comment: @Aman Yes, that would be a good solution. But how do I archive this?

Comment: @JB File size does not matter, you're right. (Although the periodic table in the JSON format is about 70 kb ... OK, not too much :D  )

Comment: @Aman I edited the question to ask a clearer question.

Comment: @Sean Thank you for your recommendation but I already found a few libs.

Comment: Might it be more efficient to try a map instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since:

- the information about elements is totally static
- each elemental symbol is alphanumeric
- the discovery of new elements is both rare and irrelevant (because they are extremely unstable)

An enum seems a good option:

```
public enum Element {
    H(1, "Hydrogen", 1.008, -259.1),
    He(2, "Helium", 4.003, -272.2),
    Li(3, "Lithium", 6.941, 180.5),
    // ... 90+ others
    ;

    private static class Holder {
        static Map<Integer, Element> map = new HashMap<Integer, Element>();
    }

    private final int atomicNumber;
    private final String fullName;
    private final double atomicMass;
    private final double meltingPoint;

    private Element(int atomicNumber, String fullName, double atomicMass, double meltingPoint) {
        this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.atomicMass = atomicMass;
        this.meltingPoint = meltingPoint;
        Holder.map.put(atomicNumber, this);
    }

    public static Element forAtomicNumber(int atomicNumber) {
        return Holder.map.get(atomicNumber);
    }

    public int getAtomicNumber() {
        return atomicNumber;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public double getAtomicMass() {
        return atomicMass;
    }

    public double getMeltingPoint() {
        return meltingPoint;
    }
}
```

There's a bit of java kung fu going on here that deserves an explanation. The map is put inside a static inner (holder) class so it gets initialized *before* the enum instances are initialized, that way they can add themselves to it. If not in the inner static class, it would not be initialize, because the first thing initialized *in the enum class* must be the instances, but static inner classes are initialized *before* the class is initialized.

This approach means the the instances don't need to be listed in any particular order (they could be alphabetical listed, or otherwise).

Comment: OK, that seems logic, but how do i replace "... 90+ others"? That is the interesting part here.

Comment: And how do I search by atomic number?

Comment: @felixd See edited answer for look up by atomic number. Regarding the "other 90+" - google it and type it in (only need to do this once ever)

Comment: I managed to convert [this JSON file's](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-pte/downloads/detail?name=jquery.pte.json&can=2&q=) relevant information into a java hardcoded enum. I also added a few other methods. This is a singletone implementation an requires less than 0,001 seconds to load. (On my Laptop :) )

Comment: @felixd Why do you keep vandalising my post? Your attempted edit completely changes the nature of the answer, and importantly removes a key part of it. Please stop trying to post your full implementation to displace my answer. If you want to publish code, try publishing it to [github](http://github.com) then post a link to your code as a comment.

Comment: Sorry for my edit, and [here](https://gist.github.com/felixdivo/11159677) is a complete implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a `PeriodicTable.txt` file with following format:

```
ATOMIC_NUMBER SYMBOL OTHER_INFO
```

Like:

```
1 H Hydrogen -> Lightest element
2 He Helium -> Second lightest element
3 Li Lithium -> Third lightest element
// and so on...
```

Then you can have a fairly straightforward implementation of your own `PeriodicTable` like following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PeriodicTable
{
  private List<Element> elements;

  public PeriodicTable() throws IOException
  {
    elements = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("PeriodicTable.txt"));
    list.forEach(this::process);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    final PeriodicTable periodicTable = new PeriodicTable();

    System.out.println(periodicTable.getElementByNumber(1));
    System.out.println(periodicTable.getElementBySymbol("Li"));
  }

  private void process(String line)
  {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line))
    {
      int atomicNumber = scanner.nextInt();
      String symbol = scanner.next();
      String info = scanner.nextLine();

      elements.add(new Element(atomicNumber, symbol, info));
    }
  }

  public Element getElementByNumber(int atomicNumber)
  {
    return elements.stream().
      filter(e -> e.atomicNumber == atomicNumber).
      findFirst().orElse(null);
  }

  public Element getElementBySymbol(String symbol)
  {
    return elements.stream().
      filter(e -> e.symbol.equals(symbol)).
      findFirst().orElse(null);
  }

  private class Element
  {
    private String info;
    private int atomicNumber;
    private String symbol;

    public Element(int atomicNumber, String symbol, String info)
    {
      this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
      this.symbol = symbol;
      this.info = info;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      return "[ " + atomicNumber + " " + symbol + " " + info + " ]";
    }
  }
}
```

If you see, I have created an `Element` class which holds the `atomic number`, `symbol`, and `info` of the element, and I have a list of `elements` in `PeriodicTable` class.

I read the `PeriodicTable` data from the `PeriodicTable.txt` file and process each line of the text file by parsing it appropriately and creating element for each line and adding it to the `elements`.

I also add two methods for filtering the element based on `atomic number` and `symbol` properties.

The code works in Java 8, so you should have at least that to run it, or one can easily write a code for this which will run on earlier JVMs, though it won't be as compact as this one.

Since there are just limited number of elements in the PeriodicTable, I don't bother to have elements sorted by their `atomic number` though they will be if your `PeriodicTable.txt` file has elements with increasing atomic number.

Since we know the exact number of elements in the `PeriodicTable` and its something that doesn't change frequently, the filtering methods take constant time.

All you have to do now is create a proper `PeriodicTable.txt` file which can then be used by the program.

Note: The `PeriodicTable` class can be written in better ways as well. This is just an example. I can have it as Singleton. I can even have `enum` of `Element` with hardcoded values, but I think loading data from file will keep the code cleaner.

One can even augment the `PeriodicTable` class with additional properties to each Element, by changing the `process()` method accordingly, and changing the format of the text file based on the assumptions, and augmenting the `Element` class, so that it can hold even more information.

Just for fun, following is a Singleton based solution:

```
// PeriodicTable.java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PeriodicTable
{
  private static PeriodicTable periodicTable = new PeriodicTable();
  private List<Element> elements;

  private PeriodicTable()
  {
    try
    {
      elements = new ArrayList<>();
      List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("PeriodicTable.txt"));
      list.forEach(this::process);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static Element getElementByNumber(int atomicNumber)
  {
    return periodicTable.elements.stream().
      filter(e -> e.atomicNumber == atomicNumber).
      findFirst().orElse(null);
  }

  public static Element getElementBySymbol(String symbol)
  {
    return periodicTable.elements.stream().
      filter(e -> e.symbol.equals(symbol)).
      findFirst().orElse(null);
  }

  private void process(String line)
  {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line))
    {
      int atomicNumber = scanner.nextInt();
      String symbol = scanner.next();
      String info = scanner.nextLine();

      elements.add(new Element(atomicNumber, symbol, info));
    }
  }

  private class Element
  {
    private String info;
    private int atomicNumber;
    private String symbol;

    public Element(int atomicNumber, String symbol, String info)
    {
      this.atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
      this.symbol = symbol;
      this.info = info;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      return "[ " + atomicNumber + " " + symbol + " " + info + " ]";
    }
  }
}

// Demo.java
public class Demo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(PeriodicTable.getElementByNumber(1));
    System.out.println(PeriodicTable.getElementBySymbol("Li"));
  }
}
```

Now you can use your `PeriodicTable` safely and directly as shown in the `Demo` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! "I think loading data from file will keep the code cleaner." Yes, but is it bad for performance? (OK, no it isn't if you always keep a reference to the `PeriodicTable` object)

Comment: @felixd: You just have to load the `PeriodicTable` data once during the execution of your program. It will take just few milliseconds. Its totally appropriate in terms of performance. File reading happens very fast.

Comment: @felixd: One can make `PeriodicTable` class as Singleton and then there will be no need of having a reference to the object. One can then easily query the elements by atomic number and symbol, by static method access. Its just few lines of code change.