# Nuclides enum library

Tags: java, enums, physics

I'm currently developing a program in nuclear physics and i would like to have a simple access to all nuclides.

Technical specifications are :

- Since informations are static, I want them to be hard coded. (means no external file to read) -> Enum seems to be a good starting point then.
- Each nuclide should carry :

  1. Atomic number A
  2. Mass number Z
  3. Isomeric number I
  4. Half decay time
  5. Natural decay mode
- The access via an API should be really really simple something like `Nuclides.get(Z,A,I)` or equivalent is recommended.
- The number of nuclides is almost 3000.

I tried this but it uses reflexion for the get method (example `Nuclide.get("Li10")`)and it seems to be an overkill :

```
public class Nuclide {
    public static String[] Symbols = {"H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na", "Mg", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca", "Sc", "Ti", "V", "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Ga", "Ge", "As", "Se", "Br", "Kr", "Rb", "Sr", "Y", "Zr", "Nb", "Mo", "Tc", "Ru", "Rh", "Pd", "Ag", "Cd", "In", "Sn", "Sb", "Te", "I", "Xe", "Cs", "Ba", "La", "Ce", "Pr", "Nd", "Pm", "Sm", "Eu", "Gd", "Tb", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm", "Yb", "Lu", "Hf", "Ta", "W", "Re", "Os", "Ir", "Pt", "Au", "Hg", "Tl", "Pb", "Bi", "Po", "At", "Rn", "Fr", "Ra", "Ac", "Th", "Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk", "Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md", "No", "Lr", "Rf", "Ha", "Sg", "Ns", "Hs", "Mt", "Ds","Rg"};
    private String symbol;
    private int Z;
    private int A;
    private int isomericState;
    private String reactions;
    private double decayTime;

    private Nuclide() {}
    private Nuclide(String symbol, int A, String isomericState, double decayTime, String reactions) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.A = A;
        this.isomericState = determineIsomericState(isomericState);
        this.Z = determineZ(symbol);

    }

    private static int determineZ(String symbol) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Symbols.length; i++) {
            if (symbol.equals(Symbols[i])) return i + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    private int determineIsomericState(String isomericState) {
        if (isomericState.equals("gs")) this.isomericState = 0;
        else if (isomericState.equals("m")) this.isomericState = 1;
        else if (isomericState.equals("m2")) this.isomericState = 2;
        else if (isomericState.equals("m3")) this.isomericState = 3;
        else {
            System.out.println(isomericState + " isomere inconu");
            this.isomericState = -1;
        }
        return this.isomericState;
    }
    public static Nuclide get(String name) {
        char[] nameArray = name.toCharArray();
        String symbol = "";
        String A = "";
        String I = "";
        boolean isSymbolRead = false, isARead = false;
        for (char c : nameArray) {
            if (Character.isLetter(c) && !isSymbolRead) {symbol += c;}
            if (Character.isDigit(c) && !symbol.equals("") && !isARead) {
                isSymbolRead = true;
                A += c;
            }
            if (c == 'm' && isSymbolRead) {isARead = true;}
            if (Character.isDigit(c) && isSymbolRead && isARead) {I += c;}
        }
        String classPath = Nuclide.class.getCanonicalName();
        try {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(classPath + "$" + symbol);
            Object[] objects = c.getEnumConstants();
            for (Object obj : objects) {
                if (obj.toString().equals(symbol + A + I)) {
                    Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getNuclide");
                    Nuclide nuclide = (Nuclide) (method.invoke(obj));
                    return nuclide;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


//Then all enums

public enum n {
        n1(1, "gs", 6.146000e+02, "b-:1.000000e+02");
        private Nuclide nuclide;
        n(int A, String isomericState, double decayTime, String reactions) {this.nuclide = new Nuclide("n", A, isomericState, decayTime, reactions);}
        public Nuclide getNuclide() {return nuclide;}
    }
    public enum H {
        H1(1, "gs", 0.000000e+00, "s"),
        H2(2, "gs", 0.000000e+00, "s"),
        H3(3, "gs", 3.891050e+08, "b-:1.000000e+02"),
        H4(4, "gs", 1.000000e-22, "n:1.000000e+02"),
        H5(5, "gs", 8.000000e-23, "n:1.000000e+02"),
        H6(6, "gs", 3.200000e-22, "nn:1.000000e+02");
        private Nuclide nuclide;
        H(int A, String isomericState, double decayTime, String reactions) {this.nuclide = new Nuclide("H", A, isomericState, decayTime, reactions);}
        public Nuclide getNuclide() {return nuclide;}
    }
    public enum He {
        He3(3, "gs", 0.000000e+00, "s"),
        He4(4, "gs", 0.000000e+00, "s"),
        He5(5, "gs", 7.600000e-22, "n:1.000000e+02"),
        He6(6, "gs", 8.081000e-01, "b-:1.000000e+02"),
        He7(7, "gs", 2.900000e-21, "n:1.000000e+02"),
        He8(8, "gs", 1.220000e-01, "b-:8.800000e+01,b-n:1.200000e+01"),
        He9(9, "gs", 7.000000e-21, "n:1.000000e+02"),
        He10(10, "gs", 2.700000e-21, "nn:1.000000e+02");
        private Nuclide nuclide;
        He(int A, String isomericState, double decayTime, String reactions) {this.nuclide = new Nuclide("He", A, isomericState, decayTime, reactions);}
        public Nuclide getNuclide() {return nuclide;}
    }
    public enum Li {
        Li4(4, "gs", 9.100000e-23, "p:1.000000e+02"),
        Li5(5, "gs", 3.000000e-22, "p:1.000000e+02"),
        Li6(6, "gs", 0.000000e+00, "s"),
        Li7(7, "gs", 0.000000e+00, "s"),
        Li8(8, "gs", 8.380000e-01, "b-a:1.000000e+02"),
        Li9(9, "gs", 1.783000e-01, "b-:5.050000e+01,b-n:4.950000e+01"),
        Li10(10, "gs", 2.000000e-21, "n:1.000000e+02"),
        Li11(11, "gs", 8.590000e-03, "b-:9.100000e+00,b-n:8.490000e+01,b-n:4.100000e+00,b-n:1.900000e+00"),
        Li12(12, "gs", 1.000000e-08, "n:1.000000e+02");
        private Nuclide nuclide;
        Li(int A, String isomericState, double decayTime, String reactions) {this.nuclide = new Nuclide("Li", A, isomericState, decayTime, reactions);}
        public Nuclide getNuclide() {return nuclide;}
    }

// ...
}
```

I found another post which is just for [element table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738023/data-structure-of-the-periodic-table-of-elements). I didn't get the point of the private static Holder class !?

Is there a better way to define the Nuclide class (without reflexion) or I should stick to this definition ? Thank you

Comment: If it's working code then you should post it on the sister site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Since elements are uniquely identified by their atomic number, you could create a separate class `Element` with A and the name, and make `Nuclide` either refer to or inherit from `Element`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer/suggestion. I posted it on code review.